# How to redirect the "For Next" to another cell and run it if the Value is not equal?

Tags: excel, vba

The below code paste the formula from column AJ8 every 7th row down until column D is Empty. The last cell in row 7 is always value = "Missing Data". The value = "Missing Data" can move the cells from AJ7 to AI7, AH7,AG7 and so on. Depends on whan time of a month I am checking my data.
Can you please guide me how I can amend this code to find the Value = "Missing Data" in row 7 and then run the below code starting from the row 8?

I have tried with "If End ID" and "ForNext" together and the "Find" but I can make it work.

Thank you in advance.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

LastRow5 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

For Row = 8 To LastRow5 Step 7

Cells(Row, "AG").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXTJOIN(,TRUE,RC[1]:RC[31])"

Next
End With
```

Example
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsmVq.png)

Comment: `Cells(Row, "AG").Select` is missing a `.`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however, the formula is working I just want to amend it so it can find the value an then run. Any ideas?

Comment: Your narrative and code contains many contradictions. AJ8 or AG8? AJ8 or AJ7? Please read what you wrote and correct the inaccuracies.

Comment: What I wanted to say that the value = "Missing Data" can be only once in any cell in row 8, hence I wrote, "from AJ7 to AI7, AH7, AG7 and so on". I want the code to find the value = "Missing Data" in row 7 and then paste the formula based on teh conditions in the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dim i as long, LastRow5 as long, m as long

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

    m = application.match("Missing Data", .rows(7), 0)
    LastRow5 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 8 To LastRow5 Step 7

        .Cells(i, m).FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXTJOIN(,TRUE, RC[1]:RC[31])"

    Next i

End With
```

Comment: Thank you user11246173. I am new to VBA and I did not know that application.match even exist. Your help is greatly appreciated!